# Cómo debe ser la etiqueta no-sql o nosql

Tags: discusión, soporte, etiquetas

Hola trás una edición sugerida por Carlos, me dí con que no se puede cambiar la etiqueta que use en una de mis preguntas
Estás intentando crear la etiqueta [nosql]; sin embargo, la etiqueta [no-sql] ya existe. Si crees que se debe permitir esta nueva etiqueta.
Y sugiere que plantee esta duda acá, por lo que mi pregunta es: ¿ qué etiqueta es la correcta?

Answer (score 3):

Debe ser [nosql](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nosql)

Algunas referencias:

- Etiqueta en Stack overflow en inglés [[nosql]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nosql)
- Nombre en wikipedia: [NoSQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL)
- Artículo sobre NoSQL en la documentación de MongoDB: [NoSQL Databases Explained](https://www.mongodb.com/nosql-explained)

Comment: entonces como puedo borrar la etiqueta mal puesta ?

Comment: He creado esta pregunta: [Cambiar la etiqueta \[no-sql\] por \[nosql\]](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/252/cambiar-la-etiqueta-no-sql-por-nosql) para que un moderador nos ayude a editar la etiqueta

Comment: Carlos  Muchas gracias